# problems initializing a vector of vectors of an auto-inc type

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, codeblocks, c++03

I'm trying to generate a quadratic grid with cells that have an ascending number.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Simple
{
public:
    Simple(): id(genId()) {}
    static int genId()
    {
        static int g_id = 0;
        return ++g_id;
    }
    int id;
};

typedef std::vector< std::vector<Simple> > SimpleGrid;

void printSimpleGrid(SimpleGrid& grid)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < grid.size(); i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < grid[i].size(); j++) {
            std::cout << grid[i][j].id << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int dim = 3;
    SimpleGrid test(dim);
    for (int i=0; i<dim; i++) {
        std::vector<Simple> row(dim);
        test[i] = row;
    }
    printSimpleGrid(test);
    return 0;
}
```

I get this output:

```
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
```

which differs from what I expected:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

What am I doing wrong?

(I'm using Code::Blocks 12.11 rev 8629 with SDK version 1.13.14)

Comment: Are you sure about that? Because I'm getting the correct results http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ba4517515949b7db

Comment: @40two Yes, I just copy-pasted it. Maybe it's only a bug in my SDK version. ...thanks for the Coliru reminder :)

Comment: Probably because I'm getting the correct results with VC++2013 too.

Comment: Seems like vector's constructor is implemented like creating default-constructed object and filling the vector with it's copies. Note that this behavior is correct: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/

Comment: @lisyarus I think `(3) range constructor` should be used. So this wouldn't be correct.

Comment: My bad, this behavior is c++98 specific, c++11 should work for you.

Comment: @lisyarus nevertheless it was worth the discussion. see [Tony D's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24243864/2932052)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Older/C++03 compilers will see this...

```
std::vector<Simple> row(dim);
```

...and match it to this overload of the constructor...

```
explicit vector( size_type count,
             const T& value = T(),
             const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());
```

...creating a prototypical `Simple` object for the second constructor argument that is then copied to each of the `dim` vector elements.

Newer/C++11 compilers will instead match this overload...

```
explicit vector( size_type count );
```

...then proceed to invoke the constructor `dim` times to create the elements.

Details [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Tony D's great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24243864/2932052), here follows my *happy end*. In the IDE settings, I enabled C++11 compliance for the compiler. The Code::Blocks 12.11 package obviously supports not only one standard:

[image]